# Celery run two process at a time

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

I have run a celery(`VERSION: 3.1.13 (Cipater)`) worker with this command

```
celery -A man worker -l info -Q queue1 -I 'myfunction' -n worker1.%h
```

configure:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600
CELERY_ROUTES = {
   'myfunction': {'queue': 'queue1'}, 
}
```

so i have this queue:

```
queue1
celeryev.98fadc59-cec3-4c28-f5d0-2bdd85545a20
celery@....pidbox
```

and when I have get `top`:

```
19576 man     20   0  695m 389m  10m S   0.0 26.0   0:35.35 celery                                                                   
19624 man     20   0  699m 382m 3076 S   0.0 25.5   2:01.30 celery
```

everything working correct but why celery was run two process with heavy memory usage while I run 1 worker?

Comment: One is the process manager which manages the actual worker processes. You should also be looking at resident memory size and not virtual memory size.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Is it normal a process manager use memory equal to worker process?

Comment: Worker processes are normally a fork of the manager process and so initially are an exact copy of it. At that time they would use the same amount of memory. Whether the worker then goes on to use more depends on what the worker process actually does.